# Setting environment variables in a ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, environment-variables, env

I'm making a simple RubyGem (no Rails) that uses the Mail gem to send out emails from the CLI. In order to configure the mailer I have to supply a password, which I want to store secretly in an ENV variable or something so that it's not public.

I tried to use Dotenv but found that after installing my newly built gem, it only works when I am running it from the project directory. If I try to run the gem from my home directory, the ENV variable is no longer accessible.

In the gemspec `spec.files` I made sure to include the `.env` file.

I don't think I'm understanding the actual process for loading variables into a RubyGem.

Answer (score 2):

Dotenv is a tool used to ship your environment variables around to different execution environments (e.g. development, staging, production, etc.), and it's not really intended for usage within a gem. The reason this only works when you run the script within the project directory is because that's how Dotenv is designed to work.

Try using the `ENV` global variable instead (which just loads the environment variables from your machine), and instructing your users to set the environment on their own, rather than having a `.env` file within the gem. That *should* allow running the script from anywhere, assuming there are no other issues.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the correct behaviour depends on the current working directory at time of invocation suggests that this is a relative path issue.  Since it works at least some of the time, your `gemspec` setup must be correct.

I haven't used `Dotenv` myself, but looking through the source suggests that giving an explicit path to your `env` file through `Dotenv.load` is the way forward.

Try using `Dotenv.load(File.expand_path("../.env", __FILE__))` from `bin/myapp`, or adapt to your directory structure (assuming the `env` file is in Gem root).

A similar approach is discussed in [this tutorial](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2014/01/17/dotenv-for-multiple-environments/).